# What's the correct way to use pre-Angular, DOM-manipulating Javascript in Angular(9)?

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js, angular9

Although Angular is mature there are still lots of useful components and utility libraries that don't yet have Angular wrappers for them.

I'm currently looking at one called [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/#initialize) for adding an image carousel and it uses a very nice (but also very pre-Angular) syntax for initialising the image carousel. (It actually has a third-party [wrapper](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper) but I'd like to understand how to build my own):

#### Swiper (pre-angular) HTML

```
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

### Swiper Javascript API

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100
});
```

## What's the best way to integrate this into Angular?

I think I can muddle through the practialities of forcing this through. What I'm really interested in though is what's the `Angular Way` to do this? What approach is not going to mess with rendering cycles etc?

### Is this approach correct?

```
## mycomponent.ts

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-hero',
  templateUrl: './home-hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-hero.component.scss']
})
export class HomeHeroComponent implements  OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  // Attach the DOM element with the container to a variable 
  // that we can reference later
  @ViewChild('swipercontainer', {read: ElementRef})
  swipercontainer: ElementRef;

  // once the view has been initialised, run the Swiper functionality
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    new Swiper(this.swipercontainer, {
      speed: 400,
      spaceBetween: 100
    });
  }
}
```

```
## mycomponent.html

<div #swipercontainer class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

*NB I haven't run this script so are almost certainly syntactic errors - what I'm more interested in is whether the approach is the correct one*